# Sql Server - Rows Summing Up Based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

i'm using Sql Server and i have to reduce some rows that have a condition, and sum the hour field into a new row.

The condition is something like this

**If ID1 == (1 or 2) and ID2 and YEAR are the same, hours should be summed up in a new row with ID1 = 4**

| ID1 | ID2 | YEAR | HOUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2441 | 2021 | 4,03 |
| 2 | 2441 | 2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 2468 | 2021 | 30 |
| 2 | 2468 | 2021 | 31,21 |
| 3 | 2441 | 2021 | 145,99 |

**Result**

| ID1 | ID2 | YEAR | HOUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2441 | 2021 | 4,03 |
| 4 | 2468 | 2021 | 61,21 |
| 3 | 2441 | 2021 | 145,99 |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression.  To avoid repeating it, I would suggest using `values()`:

```
select v.id1, t.id2, t.year, sum(t.hour)
from t cross apply
     (values (case when id1 in (1, 2) then 4 else id1 end)
     ) v(id1)
group by v.id1, t.id2, t.year;
```

Note:  This combines other rows with the same `id1`/`id2`/`year` into one row.  If you don't want this, then you need a unique id in the original table.  You can handle that with:

```
select v.id1, t.id2, t.year, sum(t.hour)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (values (case when id1 in (1, 2) then 4 else id1 end)
     ) v(id1)
group by v.id1, t.id2, t.year,
         (case when id1 <> 4 then seqnum end);
```

Answer (score 0):

you seems to want to `GROUP BY` `ID2` and `YEAR`

```
SELECT ID1 = (SELECT MAX(ID1) FROM tbl) + 1,
       ID2,
       [YEAR],
       [HOUR] = SUM ([HOUR] )
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ID1 IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ID2, [YEAR]

UNION ALL

SELECT ID1, ID2, [YEAR], [HOUR]
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ID1 NOT IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case ID2 and YEAR are like above, an approach would be simply changing the ID1 with a case (or IF) and summing with a GROUP BY

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ID1 IN (1,2) THEN 4
            ELSE ID1
       END 
      ,AVG(ID2)
      ,AVG(YEAR)
      ,SUM(HOUR)
    FROM Table1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ID1 IN (1,2) THEN 4
            ELSE ID1
         END
```